# How to retrieve data save in Model Class Swift 3

Tags: swift

I am trying to retrieve data saved in the Model file from View Controller 2, but I'm getting zeroes.  How can I save and retrieve data in Model class from any View Controller in my project?

Model.swift:

```
class Model {

    var hoursTaken = 0.0
    var currentGPA = 0.0
    //var classArray: [String]

    func saveGPA(GPA: Double) {
        currentGPA = GPA
    }

    func returnGPA() -> Double {
        return currentGPA
    }

    func saveHoursTaken(HoursTaken: Double) {
        hoursTaken = HoursTaken
    }
}
```

In View Controller 1:

```
var model = Model()     

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if pickerView.tag == 1 {
        let hourstaken = Double(choices[row])
        print(hourstaken!)
        hoursTakenText.text = choices[row]
        model.saveHoursTaken(HoursTaken: hourstaken!)

        //print(model.hoursTaken)
    } 
    else if row < 12 {
        let currentGPA = Double(choices2[row])
        print(currentGPA!)
        model.saveGPA(GPA: currentGPA!)
        GPATextField.text = choices2[row]
    }

    subView.isHidden = true
    subview2.isHidden = true
}
```

In View Controller 2 prints 0.0:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ThirdViewController: UIViewController {

    var model = Model()

    @IBAction func testButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("Test Button Pressed")
        let a = model.returnGPA()//prints 0.0
        print(a)    
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to save and retrieve data in Model class from anywhere. I think you can use `static`/`class` keyword before properties and methods in Model class:

```
class Model {

    static var hoursTaken = 0.0
    static var currentGPA = 0.0

    class func saveGPA(GPA: Double) {
        currentGPA = GPA
    }

    class func returnGPA() -> Double {
        return currentGPA
    }

    class func saveHoursTaken(HoursTaken: Double) {
        hoursTaken = HoursTaken
    }
}
```

In View Controller 1:

```
// var model = Model() // Remove this line

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    if pickerView.tag == 1 {
        let hourstaken = Double(choices[row])
        hoursTakenText.text = choices[row]
        Model.saveHoursTaken(HoursTaken: hourstaken!)

    } else if row < 12 {
        let currentGPA = Double(choices2[row])
        GPATextField.text = choices2[row]
        Model.saveGPA(GPA: currentGPA!)
    }

    subView.isHidden = true
    subview2.isHidden = true
}
```

In View Controller 2:

```
// var model = Model() // Remove this line

@IBAction func testButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let a = Model.returnGPA()
}
```

Comment: @jean: In `Model` class, if you declare `hourTaken` and `currentGPA` are public variables then why we need to add `saveGPA`, `returnGPA` and `saveHoursTaken` functions? Why not access directly to `hourTaken` and `curentGPA`?

Comment: Thanks so much, I''ll try it!

Comment: Will it also work with an array?  I need to add that later.

Comment: The short answer is **YES**. It still works with an array, you just need to change the data type of the variable. If you need to find out more about `static/class` keyword, [this article can help you](http://en.swifter.tips/static-class/)

Comment: Thank you so much!